What is the time complexity of determine_build_order function below?
Problem statement: Find out the order in which projects should be build such that dependencies are built first. Dependencies are represented using a list of pairs of projects, where the second project is dependent on the first project. See test case for details.
My attempt:
Initialization of dependency based dictionaries take O(E) time. Initialization of buildOrder array takes O(P) time. Where P is number of projects and E is number of edges/dependencies.
Does the while loop take O(E) time?
I assume that for loop inside while loop will run in total once for each edge. In other words, you can also say that outer while loops runs P times and inner for loop runs E/P times on average. So, time complexity of while loop is O(P*E/P) = O(E). Is this statement correct?
Thus, beyond initialization, it only takes O(E) to solve the problem.
from collections import defaultdict

class NoValidBuildOrderError(Exception):
    pass

def determine_build_order(projects, dependencies):
    parentMap = defaultdict(set)
    childrenMap = defaultdict(set)
    for d, p in dependencies:
        parentMap[p].add(d)
        childrenMap[d].add(p)
    pointer = 0
    buildOrder = [p for p in projects if not parentMap[p]]
    while len(buildOrder) < len(projects):
        try:
            currentProject = buildOrder[pointer]
        except IndexError:
            raise NoValidBuildOrderError()
        for child in list(childrenMap[currentProject]):
            parentMap[child].remove(currentProject)
            if not parentMap[child]:
                buildOrder.append(child)
        pointer += 1
    return buildOrder  

def test_determine_build_order():
    projects = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
    dependencies = [
        ("d", "g"),
        ("a", "e"),
        ("b", "e"),
        ("c", "a"),
        ("f", "a"),
        ("b", "a"),
        ("f", "c"),
        ("f", "b"),
    ]
    build_order = determine_build_order(projects, dependencies)
    print(build_order)
    for dependency, project in dependencies:
        assert build_order.index(dependency) < build_order.index(project)


def test_impossible_build_order():
    projects = ["a", "b"]
    dependencies = [("a", "b"), ("b", "a")]
    try:
        determine_build_order(projects, dependencies)
    except NoValidBuildOrderError:
        return  # Expected error, test passes
    raise AssertionError("Expected NoValidBuildOrderError, but it wasn't raised.")

def run_tests():
    test_determine_build_order()
    test_impossible_build_order()
    print("All tests passed!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_tests()


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Yes, your analysis is mostly a correct. The while loop takes ( O(E) ) time because the for loop inside processes each edge exactly once over the course of the algorithm. This makes the total time complexity of your implementation:
[
O(E + P)
]
where:
( E ) is the number of dependencies (edges),
( P ) is the number of projects (nodes).  hope this helps
